# Switch Statement is not displaying the second number entered

Tags: c#, syntax, switch-statement

The purpose of this test is to get the user to enter in one number, then display the second number entered. I've been trying to work out how to do it, but don't know the proper question to ask yet, I'm rather new to C#, though I have a fair amount of experience with simple C++ programming. One of the original C# programs that I wrote did a math equation, and when I did a second math equation the default variable had changed, and so the answer had changed. The second math equation would always come out wrong for this reason. I want a similar result with this now on purpose, I can't go back and look at that old program to see what I did because I deleted it because it didn't do what I wanted at the time. I have a related question, which is when exactly is a variable changed from it's default to something else?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number: ");
        int degrees = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (degrees)
        {

            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered in {0}", degrees);
                break;

            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number: ");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("You entered in {0}", degrees);
                break;



        }
```

Comment: you need to store the input from `Console.ReadLine()` in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

The second call to `Console.ReadLine()` discards the user's input without using it.

```
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number: ");
            //  Result of call not used. 
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered in {0}", degrees);
            break;
```

That second call to `Console.ReadLine()` returns whatever text the user typed at the second prompt. If you want `degrees` to be the number he typed, you'll have to parse that string just like you did the first one.

```
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number: ");
            degrees = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You entered in {0}", degrees);
            break;
```

You'll need to modify case 2 similarly.

You also really ought to handle cases where the user types something unparseable like "pepe lol!1!" and hits return. But that's another question with another answer.